# J2ME Hello World NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-me

I am newbie on J2ME, I copied a simple "Hello world" but when I run the application , I get "nullPointerException". I add the code and error logs below.

Here is the code

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
public class HelloWorld01 extends MIDlet {
    private boolean paused;
    private Display myDisplay;
    private Hello myScreen;

    public HelloWorld01() {
        paused = false;
    }

    public void startApp() {
        try {
            myDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);
            myScreen = new Hello();
            myDisplay.setCurrent(myScreen.pPrincipal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
        paused = true;
        notifyPaused();
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    class Hello {

        public Screen pPrincipal = new TextBox("Example", " Hello World", 50,
                TextField.ANY);
    }

}
```

And Here is Log

> ```
>     Installing suite from: file:///C:/Users/emrek/AppData/Local/Temp/_mtj.tmpemrek/Test8068677790959588786.launch/Test.jad
> Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
>  - com.sun.ams.TaskManagerHelperImpl.getTaskInfo(), bci=46
>  - com.sun.ams.TaskManagerHelperImpl.startTaskWithOptions(), bci=29
>  - com.sun.ams.TaskManagerExtImpl.startTask(), bci=6
>  - com.sun.midp.odd.ODTEngineBase.runMIDletSuite(), bci=12
>  - com.sun.midp.odd.InstallerListenerWithExecute$1.run(), bci=23
>  - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=5
> ```

Thank you for helps,

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I can compile and run it fine without problems. Your log indicates that the `NullPointerException` comes from `com.sun.ams.TaskManagerHelperImpl`. I have no idea what that is though, since it's not something I've ever used. Some kind of framework? Or part of SDK3.x? Anyway, the problem is not your code.

Comment: I couldn't run with eclipse but netbeans can run it. It is very strange. I think, I missed  some configurations.

Comment: Eclipse plugins for J2ME development are not updated anymore. You should use only Netbeans.